# Make all possible combinations of arrays

Tags: python, combinations

Lets say you have an multidimensional array

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 5], [4,5], [9,5]])
```

I want all the possible combinations of two arrays given the multidimensional array "a" so that:

```
[[1, 2],[3, 5]] , [[1, 2],[4,5]] ...
```

I have no idea how to due this. Does someone have some suggestions and tips?

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Sure is useful that [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) exists.

Comment: Your question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements you can replace just normal list elements with your sublists and the logic is the same.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I have tried to use np.mgrid, but I didn't really understand how to us it and if it could be applied in this context. I forgot to mention that I am only allowed to use simple packages like numpy :(

Comment: `itertools` is in the standard library and is for sure 'simpler' than NumPy. (It's hard to think of a less simple library than NumPy...)

Comment: @kwinkunks Ok, I will try to use that library then :) Thank you!

Comment: is:  ````([1, 2], [3, 5]),... ([3, 5], [1, 2]),...]```` seen as an unnecessary duplicate, or is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/14193020). This code creates the list of all the combinations.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 5], [4,5], [9,5]])
combination=[]  

for L in range(len(a) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(a, L):
        combination.append([list(sub) for sub in subset])
combination
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it answered the specific question: OP wants all _pairs_.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by all combinations? This code already creates all the subsets from the empty set to the set that contains all items.